# Git: finding largest files of a large pack file

Tags: windows, git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I found some scripts to reveal the largest files in a git pack file on a mac, but it is unclear to me if these will work on Windows.  My gut is that they will not since it explicitly says run on a mac.

That said, it seems to be running...forever.

Questions:

1. will the scripts [here](http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/08/finding-and-removing-large-files-in-git.html), work on windows
2. if not, what will work?
3. if not, what is different in the repo's on mac / windows

Comment: Which git package are you using?

Comment: we are using git windows build 1.8.5.2 and bitbucket, if that is what you are asking.  Otherwise, please clarify since I'm new to git on this level.

Comment: Just to clarify, your question says 'reveal the largest pack files' (which is roughly equivalent to saying 'find the largest repos'), but I think what you mean (given the link to jessitron's blogpost) is 'find the largest files in my repository packfile(s)'. Note that quite often you'll only have one or two pack files per repo.

Comment: I think that is a correct assessment of what I want.  I could easily look at what currently exists in the directory structure, but it is the history that worries me.  It is my understanding that all of this kind of stuff is in the pack files?  Anyway, my pack files are 2GB+, so perhaps the best question is what's the safest way to reduce it

Comment: It sounds like you’re running Git for Windows or msysGit. Be sure to run the script from a bash prompt. If you don’t see disk activity while it is running, the `read` may be waiting for input. A quick check is running `git rev-list master` to be sure that it generates output. The difference between Windows and MacOS is not the repository format but the software tools and shell available. Another script that does what you want on non-bare repositories is available at https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to those scripts - if all you're trying to do is remove large files from the history of your Git repo - would be [The BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). It's only requirement is the Java 6 runtime, so it's cross-platform. It's also very fast - for an example of this, you can watch this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir4IHzPhJuI

In your case, you might want to run it with a command like:

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M  my-repo.git
```

This removes all blobs bigger than 10MB, that *aren't* in your latest commit.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: how destructive is the Repo-Cleaner?  I read the part about assuming the current commit is good and the head is protected.  Basically just meaning, I am only screwed if I need to go to history and get that 2010 version of the Android SDK that someone checked in?

Comment: Yep, that's gist of it. The BFG is fast enough that if you're worried about running it, you might as well just take a copy of your repo and do a few test runs with it, just to see what kind of size reduction you can get and how you feel about the feedback you get.

Comment: this definitely trimmed things down, getting a ton of ..does not point to valid object, could not read, bad tree object, failed to traverse parent errors

Comment: when are you getting those errors- during The BFG clean-up or during some other operation?

Comment: after gc --prune=now --aggressive, git status gives me the could not read errors though

Comment: I've not seen that before, but I think possibly it's because you're using a non-bare clone? ('git status' is a command that only operates on non-bare repos). See http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage for more details

Comment: my repo is so large the bare-clone is failing with RPC-failed; result=18